# Is it possible to change (modify) Custom Site Template name?

Tags: 2010, site-template, custom

Is it possible to change the name of my Custom Site Template?

Right now I have a custom site template, the name of this template is **"Member Template"**

And I would like to change the name to **"POST Template"**

Can I change the name without creating another template? I have several sites that already use the "CAST Template". Can I change the name directly? If no, do I have to create the same template but with a different name?

On the [Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979709%28v=office.12%29.aspx), it says you can create a new site template but not move or change the site template.

Thank you!

I'm using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any supported method of renaming a Site Template, but will also be a lot easier to just recreate it with the new name.

1. Create new Site using template
2. Save new Site as template with new name

The sites that has been created using the "old" template has absolutely no idea that they was created base on it, so it can be deleted without causing any problems. These sites think they were created using the Site Definition that was used when creating the Site Template, so that Site Definition can't be changed and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the site collection and select Site Actions > Site Settings.  Under Galleries, select Solutions (must have privalages set for this).  This should bring up a list of .wsp files (your templates) with the ability to edit the name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very easy and does not require re-creating your template from your template as suggested by others.

### Steps

1. Navigate to the **Site Collection Settings**.
2. Click "**Solutions**" (under the Galleries section) - this shows all your site templates.
3. Mouse-over the drop-down menu for your site template and click "**Deactivate**", then click the "Deactivate" button in the modal popup that displays.
4. Click the "Edit Document Properties" icon for your site template.
5. **Change** the name of your site template.
6. Repeat Step 3; this time clicking "**Activate**" for your site template.
7. Done.